# Difference between multimethods and overloading

Tags: programming-languages, semantics, functional-programming, object-oriented

### Context

I've been programming in java for a few years now. And atm i'm learning something totally different: Clojure.
There the expression problem can be solved by using multimethods whereas in java you will need something like the visitor pattern or something alike.

### The question

I've been reading about multimethods and got quite confused with the actual difference with method overloading.

The only difference I spotted so far that a multimethod doesn't depend on the runtime type of the object on which the method is called.

Comment: In order to make this a general question (i.e. independent of concrete programming languages) you should include a short description of what "multimethods" are.

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1801216/671013

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Overloading is when two or more methods have the same name but different signature (different argument types, different number of arguments). Overloading is resolved statically, depending only on the static types of the arguments. (The interaction of overloading and overriding, in Java, for example, makes the story a little more complicated). Overloading resolves statically to a particular method signature. Then at runtime, dynamic dispatch will select the most appropriate method with that signature.

Multimethods are a collection of methods that have the same name, the same number of arguments, and *overlapping* type signatures. Whenever a call is made to a multimethod (using the name of the multimethod), all of the methods in the collection is considered as a possible candidate for dispatch. The precise candidate is chosen depending on the runtime types of the arguments – the most specific method is selected. The actual runtime types of all arguments are used to determine which one to run, which differs from traditional single dispatch in Java, where only the first argument (the target) of the method is used to determine which method body is run.

Comment: In java for example I can do this in a class
`public void do(A a){//body 1}
public void do(B b){//body 2};`


Here they do differ based on the runtime types of the arguments

Comment: The method that is selected will be based on the static type of the argument. Try it!

Comment: Ok. I'll give it a shot .. just to be sure :)

Comment: I noticed that a major part in my confusion was in the fact that I lacked a decent understanding between dynamic vs static typed languages. (and strong vs weak typed)  It makes sense now

Comment: PS: I noticed that not this year, but next year i'll be having some courses from you  :-)

Comment: From this answer, I do not get what multimethods are. What is an "overlapping" type signature? What is an example for "All arguments are used to determine which method body to run."?

Comment: @tgoossens: I noticed that you were one of our students.

Comment: @Raphael: I tried to elaborate on my answer a bit (though not as far as giving an actual example).

Comment: @DaveClarke I tried to write down my own answer to the problem. Is it a correct interpretation?

Comment: Sorry if I may ask: what do you mean by `overlapping type signatures`?? Does this mean that supposedly Array is inherited from Seq, so I can't put Array type and Seq type as input to two overloading methods in Java?

Comment: @WindDweller: An example of two overlapping type signatures, using `Array extends Seq` as an example, is `int m(Seq, Array)` and `int m(Array , Seq)`. A call `m(Array, Array)` could dispatch to either.

Answer (score 2):

As far a as my understanding goes:

Multimethods are a generalization of method polymorphism.

A multimethod consists of 2 parts

1. A name
2. A `dispatch method`: which will produce a `dispatch value`

Based on this dispatch value, the appropriate method will be chosen.
Overloading is a special case of multimethods where the dispatch method will return the static type as a dispatch value

In general, the dispatch method can be anything. It can return other values than the type.

Comment: This is a fairly faithful account of the story, in the sense that it generalises and unifies the way things happen. It's actually close to the notion of predicate dispatch, which is more general than multimethods.

Comment: BTW: You should encourage your classmates to use the [CS.SE] stackexchange.

Comment: Also, if you need a bachelor's project (Wetenschappelijke Vorming) in programming languages, send me an email.

Comment: @DaveClarke Glad to hear I got it right. At the moment I'm exploring really exciting stuff. It's the first time I try to step away a bit from OOP. Clojure has been great so far, but still a lot to learn. Multimethods for me have been a great way to solve the 'expression problem'. Nicely extendable (in contrast to the visitor pattern which just emulates double dispatch at a great cost of extendability).

Comment: I'll sure try to encourage them ;-)

Comment: I had no idea that we have a bachelors project? I'll take a look at that then

EDIT: apparently we don't have a bachelors project in engineering. We have 'P&O'. So "bad luck" for me :)